# Is it relevant to use dev dependencies in a Node / Express backend?

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

I understand using `package.json` dev dependencies when you build your code. But if your application is an Express backend, does it make any difference using dev or regular dependencies in package.json?

An example of a backend dev dependency I would use is `nodemon`.

The only thing I can think of is that hosting providers might somehow install only non-dev dependencies when running, but I can't find details if that actually happens.

Comment: If you don't care to structure your project correctly, then why not skip trying to decide whether to use dev or non-dev dependencies and just install everything globally?

Comment: @VLAZ because in that case I can't deploy my code :) Most Node providers, such as Render.com will make a container where dependencies are installed with `npm i` and which will have no global installations at all. I could do that if I make my own server, but that's not very cost effective and also it's a pain to manage, I have done that as well.

Comment: "*it's a pain to manage*" bingo! Same with dev/non-dev dependencies. Although that shows up slightly later if you try to mainain a project. "Do I really need X? Why do I even have it?" is a question you might ask yourself a couple of years down the line. Or worse you might be asking it *tomorrow* about somebody else's project you inherited for whatever reason. And vice versa - somebody might inherit your project and ask themselves the same questions.

Comment: And as for *why* these question are asked - what if a security vulnerability is revealed. And a client insists on checking if their software is vulnerable. This isn't a hypothetical scenario, either - I lived through this with an older Java project I inherited. There were several vulnerabilities in Java libraries that were revealed last year and out clients wanted to know were they affected (if so, they and my company had to prepare mitigation strategies) or not. One of the libraries affected was a test dependency, so we could confidently say there was no vulnerability.

Comment: With that said, if you *only* care about how easy it is to set up a project - there is likely nothing I can say to convince you to follow best practices. Even though the term "best practices" should have been enough to prevent this question. As is the fact that the whole concept of dev dependencies exist. Surely wouldn't be around if it was useless.

Comment: What you explained there sounds like a really nice answer to my question! What I was basically asking is _why_ is it best practice and you answered me right here in the comments - thanks! Maybe add your answer as an actual answer? `It's considered a best practice - even if it is not technically required. The division between dev and non-dev deps helps with project management by ...`

Comment: Sounds like you mean the log4j adventures we had :D I'm lucky I escaped Javaland before that time

Comment: Oh and by the way, `if you only care about how easy...` It's definitely not - this is why I'm asking the question! Are you somehow offended by my question? I want to try to understand the _why_ behind best practices, to truly and deeply understand what I am doing. Ease and speed of setup is very important, but it's far from the only important thing.